# Want to know notification status of an app programatically through my app

Tags: android, permissions, android-notifications

In case of android we can enable/disable notification status through settings. But I want to know the notification status of another application installed. For example when I am opening my application it checks Whatsapp notification is enabled or disabled. If it is disabled go to home page else app will toast user to disable notification status through settings. I tried a lot to find solution but not get any useful solution. Is there any way to get the status of notification of another app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `NotificationListenerService`.

Note that since a `NotificationListenerService` has privacy and security considerations, users have to activate this manually and will be warned against doing so by Android. As a result, many people will elect not to install your app or not to enable your `NotificationListenerService`.

Comment: its necessary to change the notification status before starting examination